# How to store data to database with Ajax on Model Class Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

We want to put data from view () to database. We use Ajax to running some background process (insert data to database). But We can't save the data to database. I'm appreciate and thank's a lot for any suggest and good avice do you give. I'm sorry if this is just a newbie's question.

This is the View (form, fieldset, javascript, and ajax)

```js
var popup, x, f31, f32, f33, f4, f5, f6, f7, f7a, f81, f82, f11, f14, f161, f17a1;

function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

//fungsi tutup popup
function tutupPopup(){
    _("popup").style.display = "none";
}

function prosesc11(){
    f31 = _("f31").value;
    f32 = _("f32").value;
    f33 = _("f33").value;
    $.ajax({
        url    : "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/TracerStudy_model/simpan_data_ts';?>",
        type   : 'post',
        data   : {'f31' : f31, 'f32' : f32},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    if(f31.length>0||f32.length>0){
        _("formc1-1").style.display = "none";
        _("formc1-2").style.display = "block";
        _("progressBar").value = 50;
    }else{
        alert("Maaf data anda ada yang belum diisi.")
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="multiphaseForm" id="multiphaseForm" onsubmit="return false"  
    method="post" action="<?php base_url();?>TracerStudy/masuk_data_ts"
>
<fieldset class="formc1-1" id="formc1-1"><!--fieldset pertama-->
    <!-- f3 -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <label>1. Kapan anda mulai mencari pekerjaan ?</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <input class="col-lg-1" id="f31" name="f3" type="radio" value="1" class="form-control">
            <label class="col-md-8" for="f31">Sebelum lulus</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <input class="col-lg-1" id="f32" name="f3" type="radio" value="2" class="form-control">
            <label class="col-md-8" for="f32">Setelah lulus</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <input class="col-lg-1" id="f33" name="f3" type="radio" value="3" class="form-control">
            <label class="col-md-8" for="f33">Tidak mencari kerja</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <input class="btn_c1-1" id="simpan" name="simpan" type="submit" onclick="prosesc11" value="simpan"/> -->
    <button onclick="prosesc11()">Selanjutnya</button>
</fieldset><!--formc1-1-->
</form>
```

This is Model Class

```html
public function simpan_data_ts(){
      $idAlumni = $this->session->userdata('id_alumni');
      // $default = null;
      // $satu = $this->input->post('f3');
      // $datetime = date('Y-m-d');
      // $dataSimpan = array( 'f3' => $satu);

      //$f31 = $this->input->post('f31');
      $f32 = $this->input->post('f32');
      $data = array(
        'id_alumni_fk' => $idAlumni,
        'f3' => $this->input->post('f31')
      );
      $this->db->insert('tracer_study', $data);
}
```

We hope, anyone can tell us what's wrong with it. And I have to say thank you for all your response.

Comment: Can you elaborate why can't you save the data to the db? what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Because, we had set the wrong url for ajax. Our mistake that we had set / call to the Model Class. And it's make wrong way, we can't put / store data to database. Right way is, like Nobita, and Pacio said bellow.

Comment: Edit: Indent code for readability, remove <script> tag from code snippet.

Comment: @Traktor53, Thank a lot Shiffu for your help to correcting, editing this question. It's make more easy to read, and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the model class directly from ajax, as a model class can't be accessed from an HTTP request.  You have to pass it first to a controller function, for example with a controller called Foo with a function called bar() the ajax you have would be:

```
$.ajax({
            url    : "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/foo/bar';?>",
            type   : 'post',
            data   : {'f31' : f31, 'f32' : f32},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Then in the Foo::Bar function, load model and call your function to save the data:

```
public function bar() {
$this->load->model('your_model_name');
$this->your_model_name->simpan_data_ts($this->input->post);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pacio for your good advice, I've appreciate that. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant go to codeigniter model directly.

just pass the data to the controller. there you can call the model by

```
$this->TracerStudy_model->simpan_data_ts();
```

and pass the data from controller to model by

```
$this->TracerStudy_model->simpan_data_ts($data);
```

Comment: From the model you can return the data that you want

Comment: Thank you very much @Nobita for your good advice. I've appreciate that. I will try it.

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding :)